# FSharp.Data.SqlClient on windows with dotnet core reports type 'SqlCommand' unavailable

Tags: sql-server, f#

I'm trying to use FSharp.Data.SqlClient on Windows

```
c:\...> dotnet new console -lang f# -o test5
c:\...> cd test5
```

Now add `<Import Project="fsc.props" />` to `test5.fsproj` and add `fsc.props` from `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.SDK/master/fsc.props`. Then

```
c:\...\test5> dotnet add package FSharp.Data.SqlClient
```

And edit `Program.fs` as follows:

```
open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.SqlClient

[<Literal>]
let connectionString = 
    @"Data Source=.\SQL14X64;Initial Catalog=test;User=sa;Password=***"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    use cmd = new SqlCommandProvider<"
            SELECT 1
            " , connectionString>(connectionString)
    0
```

Trying to compile it:

```
c:\...\test5> dotnet build
```

Have error:

```
 The type 'SqlCommand' is required here and is unavailable.
 You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, ...
```

Ok, installing System.Data.SqlClient:

```
c:\...\test5> dotnet add package System.Data.SqlClient
```

Have error:

```
The type 'SqlCommand' is required here and is unavailable.
You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.1, ...
```

O-key, let install 4.2.0.1:

```
c:\...\test5> dotnet remove package System.Data.SqlClient 
c:\...\test5> dotnet add package System.Data.SqlClient --version 4.2.0.1
c:\...\test5> dotnet build
```

Have error:

```
The type 'SqlCommand' is required here and is unavailable.
You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.1.0.0, ...
```

Hm... Replace with 4.1.0.0:

```
c:\...\test5> dotnet remove package System.Data.SqlClient 
c:\...\test5> dotnet add package System.Data.SqlClient --version 4.1.0.0
c:\...\test5> dotnet build
```

Have same error again:

```
The type 'SqlCommand' is required here and is unavailable.
You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.1.0.0, ...
```

Cannot really move any further with it.

OS: Windows, .NET Core: 2.1.2

Comment: I believe F# type providers (FSharp.Data.SqlClient is a type provider) are not supported on .NET Core yet

Comment: At least FSharp.Data JSON type provider is supported. Most likely this specific type provider is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure others are still struggling with this from time to time, so here is what I had to do in order to get the FSharp.Data.SqlClient running in a .NET Core project on a Mac (yes, it does work, beautifully!).

I believe most of it will apply to Windows as well, except that you won't need Mono.

At compile time you need full .NET framework, so you have to install Mono if you are running Linux or Mac. The project still compiles to clean .NET Core.

You need fsc.props in your project folder (place it in the same folder as your project file). Fsc.props contains the path to the tool to use at compile time. In my fsc.props file the relevant path was described as follows (I can't remember whether or not I had to edit it to get things running):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsOSX)' == 'true'  AND Exists('/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/fsharpc')">
          <FscToolPath>/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands</FscToolPath>
          <FscToolExe>fsharpc</FscToolExe>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Next you need to reference fsc.props in your .fsproj file, and DisableAutoSetFscCompilerPath:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <Import Project="fsc.props" />

    <PropertyGroup>
        <DisableAutoSetFscCompilerPath>true</DisableAutoSetFscCompilerPath>
        <DotNetFscToolPath></DotNetFscToolPath>
        <DotnetFscCompilerPath></DotnetFscCompilerPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="mySQLCode.fs" />
        <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Data" Version="3.3.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Data.SqlClient" Version="2.0.6" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The relevant lines are lines 2 through 8.

Of course you also have to get the Fsharp.Data and FSharp.Data.SqlClient using your favourite package manager, which will add the PackageReference lines to the project.

Happy coding

Roland